# Selenium IDE: Search for text using wildcard or how to escape '

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

How do I either search for a text using a wildcard or how do I escape the character '?

I have to find the text: Størrelser (Label 'size').

How do I do that using xpath?

I have tried different examples as:

> //li[contains(text(),'Størrelser (Label 'size')')]
>
> //li[starts-with(text(),'Størrelser')]

I need some help here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//li[contains(., "Størrelser (Label 'size')")]
```

This should do it for you. Normally the text value of 'Størrelser (Label 'size')' would be contained within single quotes as shown here, but because the actual value contains single quotes, you can switch them to doubles to avoid issues with it detecting where the xpath ends, the only option as xpath doesn't really contain a way to escape literals unfortunatley